# Getting a div to show a different color when a js show and hide effect is in place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a checkout system I have created. There are three different parts to the checkout flow. All of these parts are in the same page. The parts are:

1. Shipping info
2. Billing info
3. Order confirmation

Basically whenever someone is done with the shipping info they select proceed to billing info and then the shipping info section hides and the billing info section shows. Same for order confirmation.

At the top of the page regardless of what section is showing, I have this which we will call section labels:

```
<ul class="checkoutmenu">
    <div class="checkoutbutton" id="button1labl">1. Shipping Information</div>
    <div class="checkoutbutton" id="btnBillingInfolabl">2. Billing Information</div>
    <div class="checkoutbutton" id="button3labl">3. Order Confirmation</div>
</ul>
```

What I am wanting to happen is, in the active section the customer is in, for the section label to be a different color.

So if you are in the shipping info section, that section label be a different color.

I show and hide the different sections like this:

```
$(".shippinginfocontainer").hide();
$('.paymentinfocontainer').show("slow");
```

How can I do this? To see how I have this, my site is buyfarbest.com. It is in the checkout page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS, add a class, something like:

```
.active { /* CSS here to highlight */}
```

Then, when you do the hiding, and showing, add and remove the class to the corresponding sections:

```
$('#button1labl').addClass('active');
$('#btnBillingInfolabl').removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can change the color by jquery just as you apply the `show()` and `hide()` methods, using for example

```
$('.paymentinfocontainer').show("slow");
$('#btnBillingInfolabl').css("color", "#ff0");
```

Or, you could use CSS classes to do the same:

```
$('#btnBillingInfolabl').addClass("active");

CSS:
#btnBillingInfolabl.active{
color: #ff0;
}
```